# Javascript arrow function this keyword issue

Tags: javascript

I have following code:

```
window.$(".my-class").datepicker({
    ...
    onSelect: function() {

        var event = new CustomEvent("input", {});
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    },
    ...
```

and it works. But once I change the function to arrow function

```
window.$(".my-class").datepicker({
    ...
    onSelect: () => {

        var event = new CustomEvent("input", {});
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    },
    ...
```

i get error on `this` saying it doesn't have param `dispatchEvent`. Why my arrow function has different `this`?

Comment: Cause arrow functions have no context at all. `this` therefore refers to the function the datepicker code is in, therefore probably being *window*

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this

Comment: I see..strange is when I put a brakepoint into source file in browser devtools and I run the `this.dispatchEvent()` it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second case , this  refers to the function the datepicker function, not the actual window

if an **[`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)** appears in the top scope, its this argument will always refer to the global scope, when an arrow function inside a regular function will have its this argument the same as its outer function

Comment: Obvious duplicates don't need answers, just close votes and comments (if needed).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i am not aware of that question

Comment: It just takes a quick search. This question is asked at least weekly in the [js] tag.